# ShadowGeocoder missing in Robolectric 3.0?

Tags: android, robolectric, google-geocoder

I am trying to create a test with Robolectric 3.0 for some code that uses `android.location.Geocoder` but the `ShadowGeocoder` that is mentioned in the API (here: http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/maps/ShadowGeocoder.html) doesn't seem to be present in the released package.

Also, there seems to be no `shadowOf(android.location.Geocoder)` neither in the documentation nor in the package.

Am I doing something wrong or has anybody else run into similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-maps:3.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Why isn't it included in the main package? And do you know why ther isn't any shadowOf() for Geocoder?

Comment: Do you mean in main **Robolectric** library?

Comment: Yes, I mean the main Robolectric library.

Btw, the shadowOf is defined in the class org.robolectric.shadows.maps.Shadows